# Get sqlite3 database from disk, load it to memory, and save it to disk?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, memory

What I need to do is load an sqlite3 database from the disk into memory, work with it, and when the script exits save the in-memory database to the disk. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Disk to memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850022/how-to-load-existing-db-file-to-memory-in-python-sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is [`connect`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) to the database - you can do anything you want to with it then.

```
from sqlite3 import connect

conn = connect("/path/to/your/sqlite.db")
# Do what you need to with the database here
# Changes (inserts, updates, etc) will be persisted
# to disk whenever you commit a transaction.
```

If you need to be able to run a series of commands and roll them all back if one does not succeed you should use a [transaction](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

If you need to make a copy of the existing database, make alterations to it and then save it somewhere else *only if the alterations succeed* then you can do one of the following things:

- Create an in-memory database and then use SQLite's [`ATTATCH DATABASE`](http://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command to attach the existing database to the new in-memory database.  Once you have copied all of the data over from the existing database into the in-memory database and transformed it you can attach a new database and copy everything over again.
- Copy the existing database **file**, attempt to make alterations to it, and delete the new file if the operations did not succeed.
- Use `sqlite3`'s [`Connection.iterdump`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.iterdump) to get the contents of the tables as a SQL script which you can then pass to [`sqlite3.Cursor.executescript`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript) as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850022/python-sqlite3-load-existing-db-file-to-memory/10856450#10856450) (using either an in-memory or an on-disk connection string for your new database).

Comment: But whenever I query it, it'll query the file on the disk. I want this to run in memory (I've heard it's faster).

Comment: @Fike - unless you *know* that disk-IO is (or will be) your bottleneck you probably don't need to make this optimization - but I gave you some suggestions :-)

Comment: @Sean Vieira While I agree with your sentiment, you didn't technically answer his question.  For those of you looking for a real answer, this is one way to do it, though I haven't tested it out yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10856450/353094