# With Python's sqlite3 module, can I save the in-memory DB to disk after creating it?

Tags: python, sqlite

The `sqlite3` command line tool allows me to `.save <file>` the in-memory database without having to dump the SQL in its string/script form.

I'd like to do something similar without writing too much boilerplate code. However, I do not always want to save it, which is why I would like to avoid an on-disk DB before I actually need it.

Is there a way to do this in Python, short of dumping the SQL in string form and importing it to the on-disk file (which I know how to do and have already implemented)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a single line solution.

Backing up an `in-memory` sqlite database can be done using the iterdump method of the connection object. Of course, this is only *just* short of dumping the sql text and importing it.

```
import sqlite3
# set up a database in memory

c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE my_table (id int, name text);')
c.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'bruce'), (2, 'wayne'), (3, 'BATMAN');")
c.commit()

# write database to disk

c2 = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
with c2:
  for line in c.iterdump():
    if line not in ('BEGIN;', 'COMMIT;'): # let python handle the transactions
      c2.execute(line)
c2.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.7, you can use the [`Connection.backup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.backup) method:

```
db_mem = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
# ...
db_disk = sqlite3.connect('result.db')
db_mem.backup(db_disk)
```

This is the inverse operation of [How to load existing db file to memory in Python sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850022/how-to-load-existing-db-file-to-memory-in-python-sqlite3).