# Django - in memory sqlite in production

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a small (10MB), read-only, sqlite3 DB that I use in production.

I want to speed up my website so I'm trying to load the entire DB from disk to memory on every Django startup.

This answer explains how to do it in flask:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856450/3327587

Is there a similar solution for Django?

Comment: Probably not if you want to use Django's ORM, as that requires generating the schema beforehand. For a small database, most of the data should be cached anyway, so explicitly loading it in RAM is unlikely to help.

Comment: what do you mean by "generating the schema beforehand"? it's True that it's cached but I think the default cache size is only 2MB and also the DB might get larger to 50MB so I would still prefer to explicitly load it to memory

Comment: I mean the `CREATE TABLE` statements. Django doesn't run those at startup; it requires that you run `manage.py setup` or `manage.py migrate` first. The cache size is tunable via the [`cache_size` pragma](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) (which you will probably need to alter using raw SQL statements).

Comment: But I'm trying to load an existing database to memory using iterdump() and then executescript() like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10856450/3327587 so I don't really need to worry about "create table" as it's covered by iterdump(). My problem is that after creating the memory database with all the data I don't know how to tell django to use this memory db

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Configure memory database:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': ':memory:',
  }
}
```

and put the code you've linked to as a startup script (please refer to [Execute code when Django starts ONCE only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only)).

Comment: But django will create a new database in memory, how do i tell django to use the existing memory DB that I loaded? I need to point django to a connection or a StringIO object or something..

Comment: @DanBolofe You cannot load a byte array as a database; SQLite simply doesn't support doing that.

Comment: You can if you dump everything as sql statements and then execute them - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10856450/3327587

Comment: @DanBolofe Then run the SQL script, using the instructions on how to run code when Django starts that Adrian linked to.

Comment: I guess that's really the best option, to dump sql and then execute raw sql using cursor.execute(), thanks