# Load existing sqlite db into memory/ execute and close

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a function in python which connects to sqlite DB which has 20k rows and just executes a simple `select` query as below

```
def viewdata(mul):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mynew.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(("SELECT ad,abd,acd,ard FROM allrds WHERE mul<=?ORDER BY mul DESC LIMIT 1"),(mul,))
    data = [i for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    conn.close()
    return data
```

its kind of slow, so i want to move this into in memory Database of SQLite,  how can i copy this existing DB to in memory DB and make a `connection` and `fetch` the data and `close` it once the operations are over. Is there anything different i need to do when connecting to memory databases? are the `select` queries executed the same way like we do for on disk DB? Can someone please give me an example function

Comment: this may provide most of the needed information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850022/how-to-load-existing-db-file-to-memory-in-python-sqlite3

Comment: it does not have the information for executing our queries

Comment: once the db is in memory you can query like any other sqlite db object

Comment: Does this mul column have an index? If not, creating one will be a big speedup for the query. Probably more so than trying to load it all into memory will give.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but i cant see any doc or function which explains the inmemory DB for SQLite step by step :(